# rune и byte в чём разница?

Tags: golang

Зачем придумали 2 отдельных типа данных и в чём их отличие и назначение?

Comment: Советую эту заметку https://go.dev/blog/strings

Comment: Скорее наоборот плохо, что люди привыкли считать ещё по другим языкам, что `char` и `byte` - это одно и то же. А это не одно и то же.

Comment: @CrazyElf в c++11 определены типы `char32_t`, `std::u32string` и и особый вид строковых литералов `U""`для символов и строк в кодировке UTF-32. В java так и вовсе с самого начала `char` был типом для символов, а не восьмибитным целым. Так что это скорее к вопросу об учебниках и книгах для начинающих.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`rune` - это 32-х битный тип, представляющий юникодные символы в кодировке [UTF-32](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-32) aka UCS-4.

`byte` - это универсальный 8-битный тип.

`rune` используется для работы с не-ASCII символами в строках. Есть встроенное приведение `[]rune` для типа `string`, которое парсит строку из `UTF-8` (представление с переменной длиной байтов) в представление с фиксированной длиной байтов.

В случае не-ASCII строк разница между `[]byte(str)` и `[]rune(str)` разительна. Строка `Привет, мир!`:

```
Байты:  [208 159 209 128 208 184 208 178 208 181 209 130 44 32 208 188 208 184 209 128 33]
Руны:  [1055 1088 1080 1074 1077 1090 44 32 1084 1080 1088 33]
```

Приведение `[]rune(string)` эквивалентно вот такой функции:

```
func ToRunes(bytes []byte) []rune {
    result := []rune{}
    for i := 0; i < len(bytes); {
        r, size := utf8.DecodeRune(bytes[i:])
        result = append(result, r)
        i += size
    }
    return result
}
```

Текст программы с преобразованием `Привет, мир!` в руны и обратно: https://go.dev/play/p/9CDY9Xm_NgV

Comment: Верно ли я понимаю, что все кодировки(ASCII UNF8 UTF16) в кодах спец.символов, в латинских символах и в  цифрах совместимы  и тогда при хранении , кроме размера руны и байта(а следовательно и всего слайса) разницы не будет?

Comment: Не совместимы ..

Comment: @SpaceResearcher не понял, в каком смысле совместимы. `[]byte("Привет, мир!")` - это слайс восьмибитных беззнаковых чисел, занимает в памяти 21 байт, указатель на данные указывает внутрь строки. `[]rune("Привет, мир!")` - это слайс 32-х битных знаковых чисел, занимает в памяти 48 байт, указатель на данные указывает на отдельно аллоцированную память.

Comment: В том смысле что если фраза "HELLO world 123 @22()" то коды этих символов во всех кодировках будут одинаковы, следовательно, что в слайсе байт, что в слайсе рун , будут храниться одни и те же значения, но сами слайсы будут отличаться по размеру

Comment: @SpaceResearcher если в строковом литерале только семибитные ASCII символы (с кодами меньше 128), то `[]byte(str)` и `[]rune(str)` будут состоять из сравнимых чисел. Пример с со строкой  "HELLO world 123 @22()\a\t\r\n" : https://go.dev/play/p/syrBQPYTjNF